# creating JAR file in eclipse which includes resources.

Tags: java, android, java-native-interface

Is it possible to create jar file in eclipse which should contains java file, jni and lib (shared library)..?. I want this JAR file for android project so android application developer can use API which is there in in JAR file. For this I need create one JAR file for my own API's

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

[Look here](https://www.cs.utexas.edu/~scottm/cs307/handouts/Eclipse%20Help/jarInEclipse.htm) . I think you are searching for this .

> Creating JAR file using Eclipse IDE is pretty much easy. Follow the
>   simple steps. Right click on your project, which you want to create a
>   JAR file of. And select Export from the context menu

Comment: I know how to create JAR file but my problem is creating JAR wich include JNI and shared library i.e lib. is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

In eclipse select `Project` then `File`->`Export`->`Java`->`JAR file`

Answer (score 2):

Just exporting a jar file in Eclipse will not help you.

> You also need the *.so files to be a part of your jar file. This will not work in Android as your .so files should be kept in lib/ARCH folder for the APK to packaged correctly. This is needed as APKS are first extracted and .so files must find them selves in the correct directory after the apk is extracted or else you native method calls will give you Exceptions and will always fail.

Comment: I am not going to create all these things in android application. Just I think to do a java project which contains .so, jni then i'll create JAR file. I hope this will work.

Answer (score 1):

Yes first select export>jar

then check

- Export All output files for checked projects *(make sure you check in the trees at top your lib,jni folders)*

To include your source in *(ie your .java files)*

- Check Export java sources and resources

Comment: Thanks for ur answer. I think it may help me. will try out this :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can.

From the menu
File->Export

Or

Right click of the project then select Export option

This will appear the dialog for the exporting your project with different selection.

[image]

Select the Java from this list and expand it.

Now Select the appropriate Jar option for your application.

If you want to create simple api then select JAR filr for documentation select the Javadoc and for the executable select Runnable JAR file

After click next specify the JAR specification and finish it.